# Get the Array list based on the duplicate values in that Array Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

i have stuck up with below problem. I have got the below response.

```
(
 {
     CarrId = 102;
     CarrName = "Fast and Furious";
     CarrOptions =         (
                               {
                                   Id = 8;
                                   Img = "400.jpg";
                                   PImg = "412.jpg";
                                   PQ = "S-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 9;
                                   Img = "400.jpg";
                                   PImg = "412.jpg";
                                   PQ = "M-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 10;
                                   Img = "603.jpg";
                                   PImg = "611.jpg";
                                   PQ = "S-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 11;
                                   Img = "603.jpg";
                                   PImg = "611.jpg";
                                   PQ = "M-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 12;
                                   Img = "603.jpg";
                                   PImg = "611.jpg";
                                   PQ = "L-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 13;
                                   Img = "738.jpg";
                                   PImg = "749.jpg";
                                   PQ = "S-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 14;
                                   Img = "738.jpg";
                                   PImg = "749.jpg";
                                   PQ = "M-30";
                               }
                               );
     Status = 1;
 }
 )
```

Get the Array list based on the duplicate values in that Array Objective C.  I need to get the array based on the PImg. For example if PImg  = 412.jpg. i need the array something lik below

```
                               {
                                   Id = 8;
                                   Img = "400.jpg";
                                   PImg = "412.jpg";
                                   PQ = "S-30";
                               },
                               {
                                   Id = 9;
                                   Img = "400.jpg";
                                   PImg = "412.jpg";
                                   PQ = "M-30";
                               }
```

I have only done like getting the duplicates from the response

```
NSMutableDictionary * thisRow = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray  *pdctDtls = [thisRow objectForKey:@"CarrOptions"];

NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:pdctDtls] valueForKey:@"PImg"];
NSMutableArray *newarray = [orderedSet mutableCopy];
```

In newarray am getting the duplicate values. but if in the newarray if 412.jpg get the array related to 412.jpg. TIA

Comment: Yes, I want that list

Comment: I have already provided the response in the question

Comment: ya worked fine. thanks @Kuldeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you pass `611.jpg`, you get 3 objects.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", @"611.jpg"]; // AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
NSArray *array =[pdctDtls filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSPredicate like so:

```
NSArray *pdctDtls = thisRow[@"CarrOptions"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PImg = %@", @"412.jpg"];
NSArray *resultsWithSamePimg = [pdctDtls filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if (resultsWithSamePimg.count > 1) {
    // we have some duplicates
    // ...
}
```

But I would rather use a plain old for loop, which might be easier to debug and understand.